# "No remoted actions found to resolve" issue in Apex:Component

Tags: visualforce-component, remote-action

I am attempting to use a remote action in my apex:component to update an object, but am getting an error of "No remoted actions found to resolve !$RemoteAction.myController.applyCredit"

My apex:component is as follows:

```
<apex:component allowDML="true">
   <apex:attribute name="myController" type="testController" description="The page's controller" />
    <script>

    function CreditApply() {
        let newCredit = {};
        //BUILDING NEW CREDIT OBJECT
        let JSONUpdatedCredit = JSON.stringify(newCredit);
        let JSONOriginalCredit = JSON.stringify('{!myController.credit}');
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.myController.applyCredit}',
            JSONUpdatedCredit, 
            JSONOriginalCredit, 
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    console.log(result);
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    console.error('Event was an exception: Event Message' + event.message + 'Event Where' + event.where);
                } else {
                    console.error('Event failed: Event Message' + event.message + 'Event Where' + event.where);
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }

    </script>
</apex:component>
```

My apex class is:

```
global with sharing class testController {
    public testController() {

    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static Credit__c applyCredit(String JSONUpdatedCredit, String JSONOriginalCredit) {
        Credit__c updatedCredit = (Credit__c) JSON.deserialize(JSONUpdatedCredit, Credit__c.class);
        Credit__c originalCredit = (Credit__c) JSON.deserialize(JSONOriginalCredit, Credit__c.class);
    //UPDATE THE ORIGINAL OBJECT WITH NEW OBJECT
    try{
        update originalCredit;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
    }
    return originalCredit;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation, this should work, but it is not. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: I suspect the issue is because you are doing this in a custom component with a passed in argument of the controller.  Why not either use `$RemoteAction.testController.applyCredit` or, have the component's controller be the target of the remote action and then delegate to the testController.applyCrecit action

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried changing it from $RemoteAction. myController.applyCredit to $RemoteAction.testController.applyCredit, and am getting the same error. I don't think I understand your second suggestion, though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: another alternative: see last option on this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_remote_method_interface_params.htm?search_text=$RemoteAction)

Comment: Can you change your method to global method ?